# beautifulsoup not printing links

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm scrapping rss

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests


url = raw_input("");
re=requests.get(url);

def rss_get_items(url):    
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

    for item_node in soup.find_all('item'):
        item = {}
        for subitem_node in item_node.findChildren():
            key = subitem_node.name
            value = subitem_node.text
            item[key] = value
        yield item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in rss_get_items(url):
        print item['title']
        print item['pubdate']
        print item['link']
        print item['guid']
        print item['description']
```

I got this script parts of the script from an answer posted on this site, I'm just giving the guy credits. I forgot the original post and the name of user who posted it. Anyway I can't print links, it just not working, and I want to know why.

I could just follow the docs and do

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
# http://example.com/elsie
# http://example.com/lacie
# http://example.com/tillie
```

And that would work, but out of curiosity, I just want to know that the first method is working for printing links, just out of curiosity.

i'm using [aljazeera.com rss](http://www.aljazeera.com/Services/Rss/?PostingId=2007731105943979989)

Comment: Which URL are you using?

Comment: I tried with http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml and it worked fine, adding a URL of interest would help.

Comment: @alecxe please read my edit

Comment: @Stedy please read my edit

Comment: Tried that with no problems, are you using the full URL "http://www.aljazeera.com/Services/Rss/?PostingId=2007731105943979989"?

Comment: @Stedy here's the output on my machine http://i.imgur.com/iY4ub9m.png

Comment: I get links printed on both Win7 and Ubuntu, something else must be going on with your configuration

Comment: @Stedy bbc's  rss is working fine, seems my issue is with aljazeera only, anyway thanks for your help, at least i know that the script is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are scraping xml content, use the `xml` parser for creating your soup.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'xml')
```

Comment: doesn't seem to fix it, rather it seems that i got this error instead http://pastebin.com/B2QSzdqw

Comment: @Fischer That is a `keyerror` which is occurring because, well item has not that key. For avoiding it print it like this: `item.get('pubdate')` -this will return None in a keyerror situation. and consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I always accept answers, you can check my profile :) but before I do that I like to make sure the solution is working coz I don't like to ask questions after accepting answers, accepting answer = question is closed forever :)